# Merge two backslashes into one

Tags: rust

I have a very simple question, I want to merge the two backslash characters into one. For example consider the code below:

```
let s = "Hello, \\nWorld!";
println!("{}", s);
```

Output: `Hello, \nWorld!`

As you can see the code above escapes the backslash, I just simply don't want this behavior. instead I want to merge the two backslashes into one `\` so I can get my newline or any other thing like `\t` etc.

Comment: ```\\``` in a string literal *is* one backslash. You mean that you want to convert a backslash and an 'n' to a newline.

Comment: Why not write it with just one \?

Comment: Yes I want `\\n` to act like `\n` or `\\t` to act like `\t`. By default having `\n` gives me a newline. when getting inputs from user that contains `\n` rust adds an additional backslash to escape the backslash itself and it kind of messes up the result I need.

Comment: Replacing `\\n` with `\n` works, But It's not a general solution. replacing `\\` with `\` would be cool but it's not working.

Comment: You can't replace ``\\`` with ``\`` because there is no ``\\``, only ``\``. (use double backticks to format backslashes as code in comments, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275886/backslash-inside-backquotes-in-a-comment)